# Unity DrawWireDisc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity/Game Developpment and I wanted to do something like the guy shows in the beginning of the video: https://youtu.be/rSKMYc1CQHE?si=uy-sCvQHlVQFVZTs
So I am trying to draw those circles with the function DrawCircle(...). I'm not really sure whether it is right if I have to work with .DrawWireDisc here. Can you help me for drawing the particle/circle and the box as shown in the video? Until now I can't see those lines in my game tab nor my scene tab.

Which game objects do I have to use? Where should I put the script?

Thank you for your responses and Ideas

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class physics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float gravity = 9.81f;
    public float bounce = 0.8f;

    public Vector2 particlePosition;
    public Vector2 particleVelocity;
    public float particleSize = 1.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        particleVelocity += Vector2.down * gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        particlePosition += particleVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

        handleCollision();

        drawCircle(particlePosition, particleSize, Color.red);
    }

    void handleCollision()
    {
        // when particle moves outside of the box, invert velocity and multiply by bounce
    }

    void drawCircle(Vector2 position, float radius, Color colour)
    {
        // what should come here? I know Vector 3 is giving me errors but what else can I use?
        Handles.color = colour;
        Handles.DrawWireDisc(position, Vector3.forward, radius);
    }
}
```

I already tried using gameobjects for creating a box with colliders. I mean it worked but it wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: Could you please not spam tags? What does this have to do with `windows`? And `unityscript` is deprecated for years now.

Comment: I used windows because I am using Windows and unityscript because it is the library for the Handles method. But sorry, as I said, I am a complete beginner to Unity so I'm not familiar with deprecated methods in Unity or so.

Comment: It's not a deprecated method. `unityscript` [was a scripting language in Unity](https://blog.unity.com/community/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset), what you are using here is C#. Windows is unrelated to your question, you are not using _any_ windows related technologies, everything here is platform-agnostic. If you don't know what exactly you are using, don't tag it. `unity-game-engine` and `c#` is everything you need here. Now would you kindly remove the tags by editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

Handles only work on the SceneView, they are a debugging/design tool.
In your case, you don't see them even in your SceneView because they should be invoked inside the [OnSceneGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) method.

There are many alternatives to do a representation like this one in Unity. You can go with UI, Sprites, Shaders and so on. There is a very popular - paid - asset on the asset store called [Shapes](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/shapes-173167) that you can use. You can also search for free alternatives. After some quick googling, I found [this](https://github.com/epezent/ShapeRenderer) and [this other one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz9uszJPxkE).

BONUS TIP: whenever your code is not working as expected, refer to Unity's docs.